# Mismatch when filling yearly data into dataframe with daily data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to download data and add statistics and economic indicators, however my data is on a daily basis and the indicators are on a yearly basis.

I tried to store year/indicator pairs as a dictionary, go through each day in the dates column returned from yfinance, and populate a list with the GDP Deflator for each day using the dictionary. Then I convert that list to a Dataframe and add it as a row to the dataframe returned from yfinance and save it as a csv.

However, when I look at the csv file, the GDP deflator for 2004 shows up for the last day in 2003, and for the last two days in 2004 the GDP Deflator is that of 2005.

What am I doing wrong?

code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import world_bank_data as wb

df = pd.DataFrame() # Empty DataFrame


GDPD = []


df = yf.download(tickers = 'USDSGD=X' , period='max', interval='1d')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
date = df['Date']

SGD_def_dict = {"Year":[],"GDP_Deflator":[]}


for i in range(len(date)):

    if date[i].year in SGD_def_dict['Year']:
   
        GDPD.append(list(SGD_def_dict.values())[-1][-1])

    else:
        SGD_def_dict["Year"].append(date[i].year)
        try:
            SGD_def_dict["GDP_Deflator"].append(wb.get_series('NY.GDP.DEFL.ZS', country= 'SGP', date=date[i].year, id_or_value='id', simplify_index=True))
        except:
            SGD_def_dict["GDP_Deflator"].append(float("nan"))
        #GDPD.append(list(SGD_def_dict.values())[-1][-1])
    

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"GDP_Deflator":GDPD})

df["GDP_Deflator"] = df2


df.to_csv(r'C:..WBTEST.csv')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the year of each day to the corresponding GDP deflator in the dictionary, and then use the same value for all days in that year.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import world_bank_data as wb

df = pd.DataFrame() # Empty DataFrame

df = yf.download(tickers = 'USDSGD=X' , period='max', interval='1d')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
date = df['Date']

SGD_def_dict = {"Year":[],"GDP_Deflator":[]}


for i in range(len(date)):
    year = date[i].year
    if year not in SGD_def_dict['Year']:
        SGD_def_dict["Year"].append(year)
        try:
            SGD_def_dict["GDP_Deflator"].append(wb.get_series('NY.GDP.DEFL.ZS', country= 'SGP', date=year, id_or_value='id', simplify_index=True))
        except:
            SGD_def_dict["GDP_Deflator"].append(float("nan"))

df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(SGD_def_dict), on='Year')
df.drop(['Year'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.to_csv(r'C:..WBTEST.csv')
```